# Relativistic string tension vs non-relativistic Hooke's Law tension

Tags: forces, lagrangian-formalism, string-theory, spring, string

I don't have a specific question, I am just confused about what I have read and would like an explanation of it. On pages 118 and 119 of "A First Course in String Theory", professor Zwiebach derives the equation (6.74) $V = T_0a$ where $V$ is potential energy of a string, $T_0$ is tension, and $a$ is the length to which a string has been stretched. The derivation depends on the Nambu-Goto action $S = -T_0A$ where $S$ is the action, $T_0$ is a constant of proportionality in units of force (i.e. tension) and $A$ is the area of the worldsheet of the string. This goes against Hooke's law $V = (1/2) ka^2$ where $V$ is potential energy, $k$ is the spring constant and $a$ is the amount that a string has been stretched. (Strings don't change length appreciably under tension so shouldn't we call it spring theory?) So relativistic string tension is proportional to a while Hooke's law tension is proportional to $a^2$. This seems to violate the correspondence principle. If we replace $ka$ with $T_0$ in Hooke's law we get $V = (1/2) T_0a$ with a factor of 1/2 that does not exist in relativistic string tension. Finally, in Hooke's law, tension increases with stretch, but relativistic string tension is constant. Obviously, I am missing something.

By the way, on p.16 in professor Tong's book on [string theory](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) we have the following quote:

> "So $T$ is indeed the energy per unit length as claimed. We learn that the string acts rather like an elastic band and its energy increases linearly with length. (This is different from the elastic bands you’re used to which obey Hooke’s law where energy increased quadratically with length)."

He makes no effort to explain the meaning of this difference.

Comment: Thank you Qmechanic for your edits.